# Properties in Objective c. copy and retain

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, retain

What I have read from the apple document retain will increase the retain count by 1 , and release will decrease by 1. This is very much clear to me.

But In the case of copy and retain i am a bit confused.

Let me explain with the code i am trying.

property ---

```
   @property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *a;

   @property(nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *b;


   @synthesize a = _a ,b = _b

   a=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Hello Ankit"];
   NSLog(@"a memory location A - %p", &a );
   b=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Hello Nigam"];
   NSLog(@"a memory location B- %p", &b );
   c= [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Ankit Nigam"];
   NSLog(@"a memory location C %p",&c);


NSMutableString *temp =[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"hey"];

NSLog(@"temp = %@ %p",temp,&temp);
self.b = temp;
NSLog(@"B is now %@ %p",self.b,&b);

self.a = temp;
NSLog(@"A is now %@ %p",self.a,&a);

And i get the output as -- - -

2012-05-10 03:24:34.756 retainCountTest[2655:f803] a memory location A - 0x6d314fc
2012-05-10 03:24:34.757 retainCountTest[2655:f803] a memory location B- 0x6d31500
2012-05-10 03:24:34.764 retainCountTest[2655:f803] a memory location C 0x6d31504
2012-05-10 03:24:34.764 retainCountTest[2655:f803] temp = hey 0xbfffdd04
2012-05-10 03:24:34.764 retainCountTest[2655:f803] B is now hey 0x6d31500
 2012-05-10 03:24:34.765 retainCountTest[2655:f803] A is now hey 0x6d314fc
```

But as per I understand from the Doc the retain object must have the same memory address ,          where      as copy object will create a new object with different memory location.

Again when i change the logs to ---

```
self.b = temp;
NSLog(@"B is now %@ %p",self.b,&_b);

self.a = temp;
NSLog(@"A is now %@ %p",self.a,&_a);
It return me a complete different memory location for both the object.

2012-05-10 03:28:49.905 retainCountTest[2688:f803] a memory location A - 0x6d4a4ac
2012-05-10 03:28:49.906 retainCountTest[2688:f803] a memory location B- 0x6d4a4b0
2012-05-10 03:28:49.907 retainCountTest[2688:f803] a memory location C 0x6d4a4b4
2012-05-10 03:28:49.907 retainCountTest[2688:f803] temp = hey 0xbfffdd04
2012-05-10 03:28:49.908 retainCountTest[2688:f803] B is now hey 0x6d4a4c0
2012-05-10 03:28:49.908 retainCountTest[2688:f803] a is now hey 0x6d4a4bc
```

Can any help me to understand the complete concept of these retain and copy. Also why I am     getting these unexpected results.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that `&_b` is the address of the variable _b and not the address of the object;  thus, `&_b` and `&_a` will be different regardless and, quite easily, may be different on subsequent runs of the same method depending on the call stack.

Comment: +1 and, @ankit, that applies to all of your uses of `&`. You're not logging what you think you are.

Comment: Objective-C objects, by nature, are pointers to a structure in memory. When using NSLog, you can just use `NSLog(@"%p", object);` which will print the pointer location instead of the object's -description method.

Comment: Frankly, if you haven't figured out the retain/release stuff by now you should just skip it and go straight to ARC.

Comment: It's not that hard: -retain objects passed to you that you wish to own as a global object, and -release it when done. -copy objects you want to keep for yourself, and assign objects only when you want to keep a weak reference for it. ARC is the same game- different names. In fact, I'd argue that for bridging and weak types, etc, ARC is a horrible choice. It needs to be improved first.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A property is just a declaration that allows for setters, getters, and dot-syntax accessors (interface variable hiding).

It does absolutely nothing on its own but allow you to use `-[myInstance myProperty]` to get the variable or use `-[myInstance setMyProperty:]` to set it (yes, the method name is auto-assigned to `-setProperty:` and `-property`).

When declaring a property, you have three categories - thread locking, access control, and memory management. You can only pick one of the modifiers for each category and if you do not pick one, it's auto-assigned to one automatically.

`@property (<thread locking>, <access control>, <memory management>) id property;`

The first category can either be `atomic` or `nonatomic`. The `atomic` modifier forces an @synchronized(myInstance) lock on the variable, to allow thread safety. The `nonatomic` does not use a synchronized-block, and is NOT thread safe. If you do not use either, it is automatically set to `atomic`.

The second category can either be `readonly` or `readwrite`. The `readwrite` modifier allows the property to be modified as well, and allows auto-generation of the -setProperty: method. When the `readonly` modifier is used, you cannot use the `-setProperty:` method. You must use the internal variable from within the object to set the variable directly.

The third category can either be `assign`, `retain`, and `copy`. The `assign` modifier means the internal object pointer is set to the pointer passed to the `-setProperty:` message. The `retain` modifier assigns the passed pointer and passes a `-retain` to the object.

The `copy` modifier does a straight-up clone of the object- a new pointer to a new object at a new address in the memory. This sets the internal object pointer to the copy of the passed object, by calling `-copy` on the passed object. The default modifier is `assign`, and the compiler will warn you if you do not set the memory management category modifier on an object - because an `assign` modifier on an object is frowned upon (unless explicitly declared).

For an example on -copy, look at this:

```
- (void)setProperty:(GXMyObject *)property {

    // This points to the original passed object.
    GXMyObject *original = property;

    // This points to a copy of the passed object.
    CGMyObject *copied = [property copy];

    // This points to yet another copy of the passed object-
    // Independent of the other copies and original.
    _property = [property copy];

    // The anotherProperty is now different on this copy
    // than on the original and the other copies.
    _property.anotherProperty = 4;

    // This will prove that they are all individual objects.
    NSLog(@"%p, %p, %p", original, copied, _property);
}
```

There is an optional method name declaration modifier and is used like so: `getter = myCustomPropertyGetter` and `setter = myCustomPropertySetter:` (The colon `:` at the end of the setter method name is required because it denotes that an argument must be passed).

The second half of this is the property synthesizer or dynamizer. Once a property is declared (for example, `myView`) like so:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSView *myView;`

You would either: define the setter and getter yourself; `@synthesize` the setter and getter; `@dynamic` the property to say that it exists in a category or the main class, or may be added at runtime (not a fun idea, mind you, and could cause bad runtime exceptions).

The first example, writing the methods yourself would look like this:

```
// In Apple's LLVM 3.1 Compiler, instance variables can be added 
// within {} below the @implementation as well as the @interface, 
// and in private categories (@interface GXMyClass ()) like before.
@implementation GXMyClass {
    // The internal object pointer is prefixed with an _ to avoid name confusions.
    NSView *_myView;
}

- (NSView *)myView {
    return _myView;
}

- (void)setMyView:(NSView *)myView {
    _myView = [myView retain];
}

@end
```

The second example would be to auto-synthesize it using the `@synthesize` directive:

```
@implementation GXMyClass

// In the new Apple LLVM 3.1 Clang compiler, the = operator when used 
// next to the @synthesize directive declares an internal private 
// variable and automatically sets to that variable.
@synthesize myView = _myView;

// The internal variable name is now myOtherView, because we did not use the
// = operator to assign an internal variable name to the property.
@synthesize myOtherView;

@end
```

Under the last example, perhaps the most confusing, because it requires the use of the @dynamic directive, you require something of a category or a runtime method addition:

```
@interface GXMyClass (InternalMethods)
@end

@implementation GXMyClass

// The = assignment operator does not work here.
@dynamic myView;

@end

@implementation GXMyClass (InternalMethods)

- (NSView *)myView {
    return [self methodThatReturnsAnNSView];
}

- (void)setMyView:(NSView *)myView {
    [self methodThatAcceptsAnNSViewArgument:myView];
}

@end
```

The `@property` declaration requires one of the three above declarations to be present- it does not do anything on its own. What it DOES allow, however is dot-syntax accessors (Java-like accessors for setting and getting properties).

For example, `@property (copy) NSString *myName;` could be accessed using `-[myObject myName]` and set using `-[myObject setMyName:]`.

Now it can be set using `myObjectInstance.myName = @"Bob";` and gotten using `myObjectInstance.myName`. Utilizing all the above concepts, one could create an object such as this one:

```
// The GXBufferQueue is a queue which buffers all requests, till they are read
// asynchronously later. The backing store is an NSMutableArray to which all
// buffer writes are appended to, and from which the first object is pulled and
// returned when the buffer is read to.   
@interface GXBufferQueue

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy, setter = write:, getter = read) id buffer;

+ (GXBufferQueue *)queue;

@end

@implementation GXBufferQueue {
    // This queue is an internal array and is 'tacked on' to the @implementation
    // so no others can see it, and it can be marked @private so subclasses cannot
    // use it. It is also good code practice to have @interfaces composed of only
    // @properties, setters, and getters, rather than expose internal variables.
    NSMutableArray *_internalQueue;
}

+ (GXBufferQueue *)queue {
    return [[[GXBufferQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (id)init {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        _internalQueue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)write:(id)buffer {
    [_internalQueue addObject:buffer];
}

- (id)read {
    if(!(_internalQueue.count > 0)) return nil;

    id buffer = [_internalQueue objectAtIndex:0];
    [_internalQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    return buffer;
}

@end
```

Note: This code was in no way tested.
Now that you have a GXBufferQueue, all the following works:

```
GXBufferQueue *queue = [GXBufferQueue queue];

// Option One: using the traditional message syntax:
[queue write:@"This will be now added to the buffer."];
NSLog(@"Now the string written to the queue will be read \
and removed from the queue, like a stack pop. ", [queue read]);

// Option Two: using the new dot-syntax accessors:
queue.buffer = @"As clunky as this looks, it works the same as above.";
NSLog(@"These lines work just the same as the ones above: ", queue.buffer);
```

As you can see, there's a lot possible with properties and a lot more that can be done with them than just variable declaration. If there are any questions or anything the community would like me to add/rectify to/in the post, please leave a comment! :D

Comment: Another footnote in your code: Don't rely on -retainCount: it's faulty in many cases (including GCD and PDO).

Comment: thank you Galaxas for a nice explanation.so from this can i make out that a object of retain type when assigned to object of copy type (if mutable) a new copy object with new location will be created. Please correct me if i am still wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. To map it out, let me explain it like this: an object to whom you pass -copy, is no longer the same object as before: it resides in a new memory location with the exact same contents as the original. I'll update my answer to explain this.

Comment: Thank You Galaxas0 , Your explanation helped me a lot.

Comment: @Galaxas0: `copy` may or may not return a new object

Comment: It's *supposed* to return a new object, if you implemented NSCopying properly.

Comment: No, -copy is not **supposed** to return a new object.  It only does so if a new instance is required.  Immutable objects are not copied, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `retainCount` is useless-- don't call it-- and assuming that `copy` will always return a new instance is incorrect.

If an immutable object is sent `copy`, it will typically be implemented as:

```
- copy { return [self retain]; }
```

I.e. there is no need to make an actual copy since the contents can't change.

Of course, since you are mucking about with static, compiled into the binary, strings, the implementation is likely closer to:

```
- retain { return self; }
- copy { return self; }
- (void)release { ; }
- (void)dealloc { ; }
```

Maybe -- all of the above are implementation details that may change at any time.  The bottom line, though, is that all of the above fulfills the contract of retain/release/copy/etc...