# Duplicate a variable with different memory address

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, pointers, memory-management

I'm trying to make a new instance of a variable that contains the same properties' values of another variable.

I can't assign them directly as I did in the code below, because in this case both of them will be point to the same memory address.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
      UITextField * newTextField = [UITextField new];

      newTextField = textField; // the problem goes here ( same memory address )

      [self.view addSubview:newTextField];
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      [textField removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I figured out an impractical way to do so by setting each property by its own.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
     UITextField * newTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textField.frame];
        newTextField.font = textField.font;
        newTextField.text = textField.text;
        newTextField.textColor = textField.textColor;
        newTextField.textAlignment = textField.textAlignment;
        newTextField.center = textField.center;
        // ...
        // ...
}
```

But in this case I have to set each individual property the new instance, which I found impractical.

Isn't there a better way to set the old variable to the new one without changing the new variable's memory address.

Comment: does `UITextField` conform to `NSCopying` protocol?

Comment: I guess you need to define your `textField` as a property like `@property (nonatomic, copy) UITextField * textField;` and then when you try to assign it to another pointer, it will copy your initial text field object. Here is some explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524772/properties-in-objective-c-copy-and-retain

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What is the purpose of replacing a text field with another one that's identical?

Comment: `newTextField = textField` is definitely a problem;  that merely sets `newTextField` to point to whatever `textField` points to.  It would be the same as `int x = 1; int y; y = x;`.   Your "impractical" way is, effectively, the only way.  But... what are  you really trying to do?  Such a pattern is quite odd.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev the app crashes actually with copy!

Comment: @bbum Well it's odd actually, I was trying to copy and remove the original view from its hierarchy and add the new copy to another hierarchy. But at the end, for the sake of not using stupid pattern, I'm not going to remove the original one. Thanks.

Comment: @user3607093 Why not just remove the view from the original hierarchy and shove it into the other hierarchy directly?   Still slightly odd, but not actually unheard of.

Comment: @bbum I thought removeFromSuperview would make the view null. But it seems like it's just remove it from the hierarchy not the memory. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you have to subclass UITextField and make your subclass conform to NSCopying protocol, to do that you have to implement the method copyWithZone in your UITextField subclass.